# How to change full calendar month listview hover backgroud and text color change

Tags: html, css, fullcalendar, mousehover, fullcalendar-5

I am working with an appointment booking system. this system includes a full calendar with a monthly list view.I want to change the background and text color when hover list item.it default gets a white color background. how do change it?

```
if (calev.end._d.getTime() < ntoday.getTime() ) {

     elt.css('background-color', '#5c5c3d');//change backgroud color
     elt.css('color', 'white');//change text color
     elt.find(".fc-event-dot").css('background-color','white');//change dot color
    //here I want write a hover background and text color code

  }
```

[image: Sample view]

Comment: You mean that you want to change the events background color? Depending on what? If their Start time is in the past or future?

Comment: Provide some markup also and css for the list items (and wrapper).

Comment: i need to change background color when cursor move list item

Comment: no need think about start time and end time.just want find way change color mouse hover

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a simple CSS rule to achieve this - if you inspect the fullCalendar HTML using your browser's element inspector, you can find the class it uses to identify an event in the list view, and target that.

For example:

```
.fc-list-table .fc-list-event:hover td {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Working demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/ExRjWLp

Comment: elt.find(".fc-list-table .fc-list-event:hover td").css('background-color','red');

Comment: i add this way but it did not work .why is that?

Comment: i used full calendar 3.9 version

Comment: Because `.fc-list-table .fc-list-event:hover td` isn't a selector really, because of the :hover - it wont find the element unless its already being hovered. But why would you do it like that anyway, you can just put the rule in your CSS file

Comment: okay, I will try it, bro. thank you very much for your valuable contribution

Answer (score 1):

i think this may help

```
fc-list-item:hover td{
    background-color: red !important;
    color: white!important;
}
```